# Missing 1 bit during decimal to 8-bit binary conversion

Tags: java, bit

I wrote a simple method in Java to convert a decimal number to its 8-bit binary representation. 
However, for certain numbers, it returns 7-bits instead of 8-bits but for other numbers, it works perfectly fine.

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 hours now, and have done my research on this website to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
public static void convertBinary(int n) {
    int[] arr = new int[8]; //initialized to hold 8 bit places
    int counter = 0;
    String binary = "";

    while(n > 0) {
        arr[counter] = n % 2;
        n /= 2;
        counter++;
    }
    for(int i = counter; i >= 0; i--) {
        binary = "" + arr[i];
        System.out.print(binary);
    }
}
```

When I call convertBinary(125), I get 01111101 which is the correct 8-bit representation.

However, when I call it as convertBinary(32), I get 0100000 which is missing 1 bit. The result I want is 00100000.

I thought that by initializing an array of 8 sizes would help with the 0's padding at the front, but for some reason it doesn't work. I'm at my wit's end here and again, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In your final loop, why not just print out **all 8 bits** instead of starting at `counter`?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I had to do a decremented loop to reverse the numbers as the first while loop produces a reversed result

Comment: Since your array always has 8 elements why not to start from 7 and down to 0? Like `for (int I = 7; I >= 0; --I) {}`

Comment: @Ivan That did it! However, I wonder if there is a better solution (to avoid the magic number of 7)

Comment: `arr.length - 1` since in Java arrays are zero-based index of last element is calculated like length of array minus 1.

Comment: @Ivan thank you, that worked perfectly fine. also, quick question as i just noticed something, in my code, i used i-- and in your snippet, you used --i. is that just a preference thing or is there a difference between the two?

Comment: There's a difference, but it doesn't matter **in that particular context**.  Doesn't mean you can just substitute `--i` and `i--` willy-nilly in other contexts, though...

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating from number of bits in the given number 32 which has only 6 bits. 
if you want all 8 bits then iterate from length of the bits which is 8.

```
         public static void convertBinary(int n) {
            int length = 8;
            int[] arr = new int[length]; //initialized to hold 8 bit places
            int counter = 0;
            String binary = "";

            while(n > 0) {
                arr[counter] = n % 2;
                n /= 2;
                counter++;
            }
            for(int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                binary = "" + arr[i];
                System.out.print(binary);
            }
        }
```